# Maven invalid version format: ATE:

Tags: java, maven

this is alert:
****Unable to update Maven configuration
Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): invalid version format: ATE:****

Comment: post your pom.xml

Comment: Post the full error/warning output...Which Java version are you using? Are you behind a proxy/firewall ?

Comment: thank you guys,i already done it ! it seems i can't connect Maven Repository.